# react-native-responsive-screen is not working responsively on some place

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hy,
I'm new in react-native. Recently I start using **react-native-responsive-screen** to responsive the app and it's worked for me but in some places, it's not working responsively.

```
                <View style={styles.accountTypeWrapper} >
                    <Text  style={styles.accountTypeWrapperText} >Select an Account Type</Text>
                </View>
```

**Style**

```
    accountTypeWrapper:{
        marginVertical:hp('8%')
    },
```

look that images are taken from two devices the line "Select an Account type".
What the issue of responsiveness how I can resolve it?

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Comment: Please define what the problem is.

Comment: @LajosArpad app not working responsively in some places.